# jQuery submit() - form is still sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I have this

```
$("#formNewsletter").submit(function(){

                        return false;
                    })
```

It works as expected - the form is not submited.
When i write this, it seems like it is returning true (the form is being send)

```
$("#formNewsletter").submit(function(){
                        if($("#newsletterSelSpec div").length() > 0)
                        {
                            alert("Good");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Please add at least one speciality!");
                        }
                        return false;
                    })
```

I would like to understand why is this happening and how can I make it work.

Thank you!

Comment: always use `preventDefault()` to stop the default action behaviour, as the below example - `return false` should be avoided unless absolutely necessary/understood - look up `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation` too!

Comment: the property length isn't a method.

Use `$("#newsletterSelSpec div").length > 0`.

Comment: @AndreasAL Post that as an answer, since that's almost certainly the reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the property length isn't a method.

Use `$("#newsletterSelSpec div").length > 0`.

---

You can prevent the default behavior of an event using `preventDefault()` witch is a method in the first argument. (`event`).

```
$("#formNewsletter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($("#newsletterSelSpec div").length() > 0)
        {
            alert("Good");
        }
    else
        {
            alert("Please add at least one speciality!");
        }
});
```

---

Not sure, but the problem can be that the alert stops the process of the script and not the submit event.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Radu haven't mentioned anything about submitting the form but preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that "method" I was using.. And the idea was, indeed, to never send that form, but do an ajax call instead. Thank you, Andreas AL!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#formNewsletter").submit(function(e) {

    if ($("#newsletterSelSpec div").length > 0) {
        alert("Good");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent the form submission
        alert("Please add at least one speciality!");
    }
});
```

---

#### NOTE

you're using `.length()`, but it should be `.length` only, that means

```
$("#newsletterSelSpec div").length
```

Comment: Judging from the position of the `return false` in the code in the question the form is *never* supposed to be submitted, so calling `e.preventDefault()` only in the `else` block will change the functionality.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Yes, but I suspect it was moved there in desperation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Possibly. No way for us to know either way without Radu telling us. I still think it's a good idea to make it clear when your answer doesn't exactly match the intended functionality of the code provided in the question.